# Getting Error while using grid method in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

Using Matplotlib in python, i tried this code and got below error. Pls help.

**Code**

```
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

**Error**

TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Comment: You need to show us more of the code, because clearly you have overwritten something.  EXACTLY which line produces this error?

Comment: I would assume that this means `plt` is not the object you think it is. But without seeing more of your code or know which lines produces this error, it's pretty much impossible to tell. What does `type(plt)` return?

Comment: import numpy as np  from matplotlib import pyplot as plt x = np.arange(1,11)
y=2*x  plt.plot(x,y) plt.grid(True) plt.show()

Answer (score 2):

All the thing you need is to reload the `pyplot` module.

```
from importlib import reload

reload(plt)

plt.grid(True)
```

Comment: Any idea why this works please/what caused the TypeError:'bool'?  Tku

Comment: Many people tried the `plt.grid=True` in a jupyter file first, and it caused the function invalid. Reload can solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `plt.grid()` (without True)?

Comment: Yes, But it didn't work. Nothing seems to be working when using grid method.